# To prove the properties of Denjoy's Maps

Tags: general-topology, dynamical-systems

We need to show that the Denjoy homeomorphism constructed may actually be made $C_1$.

a)For each integer $n$,let $$l_n=\frac{1}{(|n|+1)((|n|+2)}.$$Show that $$\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} l_n <\infty$$$$\lim_{|n|\to\infty} \frac{l_{n+1}}{l_n}=1.$$

b)For each $n$,let $I_n=[a_n,b_n]$ be an interval with length $l_n$. Define a map $f$ on $[a_n,b_n]$ by $$f(x)=a_{n+1}+\int_{a_n}^{x} 1+\frac{6(l_{n+1}-l_n)}{l^3_n} (b_n-t)(t-a_n) dt.$$Show that $f'(a_n)=f'(b_n)=1.$

c)Prove that $f$ takes $[a_n,b_n]$ onto $[a_{n+1},b_{n+1}]$ in one-to-one fashion.

I already solved a and b part and can anyone give me any hints on the c ones?

Comment: Did you actually try to compute explicitly? You have polynomials of degree $2$ in $t$.

Comment: yes I figured out part b ! yeah!

Comment: Hint: The RHS of the equation defining $f(x)$ is increasing with respect to $x$.

Comment: @Did So if I take difference btw f(bn) and f(an) and get a unique value, can this prove its onto?